# Flink task slots are not evenly distributed when setting operator parallelism larger than default parallelism

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm running a Flink job on a cluster containing 3 task managers (on top of 3 Kubernetes pods).
Job's default parallelism is 9 and one of the operators is set to parallelism 18.
Job's number of task slot is set to 18 (the largest parallelism value).

I observe the following behavior:

The operator set to parallelism 18 is equally distributed between all task slots.

All other operators (set to default - 9) are not distributed equally. For example:

- TM1: running 2 sub-tasks
- TM2: running 5 sub-tasks
- TM3: running 2 sub-tasks

Can someone please explain the following -

- What causes this uneven distribution?
- Can I control operator assignment to be ballanced? how can I do it?

(Running with Flink v1.6.3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, Flink does not support to control how tasks are spread across different `TaskManagers`. Flink assumes all slots to be equal and, therefore, does not try to spread out tasks uniformly. The community wants to add this functionality, though. Here is the [respective issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11815).

### Update

The problem has been fixed for Flink >= 1.9.2. In order to enable spreading out of tasks, you must configure `cluster.evenly-spread-out-slots: true` in your `flink-conf.yaml`.

Comment: Just for those who care, the issue has been solved and closed. Starting from 1.9, We now have a option [cluster.evenly-spread-out-slots](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#cluster-evenly-spread-out-slots). It is not default activated